# Pluses and stars inside square visual quiz

Tags: visual

[image]

The problem is to cut the square into four parts by going along the lines, so
that each part shall be exactly the same in shape and size, and each part contains
a star and a plus.

by H. E. Dudeney

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is the answer :

> [image]